# Recently viewed questions list broken

Tags: bug, status-completed, ios-app, recent-activity

I see many empty vertical spaces in the top & bottom of the list. 
Also "today" group has some rendering problem.
Problem occurred after selecting some question in the list and go back.

[image: recently viewed top]

[image: recently viewed bottom]

- App Version: 1.6.1.2
- Device: iPad Air 2 (Wi-Fi)
- OS Version: Version 10.0.2 (Build 14A456)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This was fixed in 1.6.4 by switching from CoreData to Realm.